# SQL Timeout to Principle Server Error

Tags: errors, query-timeout

I am seeing a timeout to the Pricincipel SQL server (2008 R2)

The exact error I am seeing is this:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
>   operation or the server is not responding. This failure occured while
>   attempting to connect to the **Principle server**.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired. The
>   timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the
>   server is not responding. This failure occured while attempting to
>   connect to the Principle server. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation
>   timed out at XXXX

What I am trying to understand is is this a standard timeout, ie. the DB was unable to return the required results within the allowed time? Or does the "**Principle Server**" wording signify another issue?

I have not been able to find much about this specific error and need to know if its a performance issue that tuning the indexes and procs will help resolve or is there another issue I need to look at instead.

Comment: What is your setup? The termin principle server is used in database mirroring. Could it be that you're try connecting to a mirrored database? How does your connection string look?

Answer (score 4):

I am currently investigating an occurrence of the same timeout exception with the same key wording:

> This failure occured while attempting to connect to the Principle server.

The environment is SQL Server 2012 with mirroring, so I suspect that the problem was not directly related to a long-running query, but rather to a temporary network/sync issue, either between the application and the SQL servers or between the SQL servers themselves. Stack trace:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.  This failure occured while attempting to connect to the Principle server. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.DynamicUpdate(TrackedObject item)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.Update(TrackedObject item)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   ...
```

**Update**: evidently, this wording is included in the exception message whenever a command times out against a mirrored/failover partner environment. It does indeed reflect a command that exceeded its timeout, and has nothing to do with a failure to attempting to connect. You can verify this by running a simple WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:31' command, which exceeds the default 30-second SqlCommand timeout, and triggers the same exception message.

I have opened a [Connect bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1423903) to ask Microsoft to correct the misleading wording in the message.

Comment: Did anything ever come of your connect issue? The link no longer works

Comment: @JoePhilllips No, I don't believe so. MS reorganized Connect recently and I can't find the issue page anymore, even if I search by the ID 1423903. But it's basically just a misleading error message. The actual problem is a normal database timeout due to a query taking longer than the command timeout. It's just that the message wrongly indicates that the failure has to do with attempting to connect to the Principle failover partner.